# Asp.net 4.0 passing apostrophe parameter through routing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, routes

I have an Asp.net 4.0 Webform Application with routing implemented, everything works fine, but now I have got some names with apostrophe and I need to pass them through URL.

```
 <a href='<%# GetRouteUrl("RouteMenu", new With {.typology= Server.HtmlEncode(Session("Type")).ToString.Replace(" ","-").ToLower, .brand = Eval("brand").ToString.Replace(" ","-").ToLower, .color= String.Empty}) %>'><%# Eval("name").tostring %><br /></a>
```

as you can see I am passing the parameter Brand which now some of them contain an apostrophe, I tried to encode it but does't work, the brand name is "It's my party"

Do you have any suggestion, I would't use the session variables to pass them it is than difficult to manage it through the vary round trips client-server.

Thank you in advanced